# suspension period

Tags: bug, account-suspension

I've read [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31202/144421) that a suspension period can last at most one year. But I found an account which is obviously suspended for $\textbf{10 years}$ :

[image]

Have the rules been changed or has an error crept into the system?

Comment: Rules have changed but not recently as far as I'm aware.  A pretty detailed account of historical and practical aspects can be gleaned from the Meta.SE post [How long can a temporary suspension be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211217/how-long-can-a-temporary-suspension-be)  Your example mentions network-wide suspension, so necessarily that was done by staff moderation.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link. A 10-years suspension can happen, but it is very rare since a user has to violate strongly against the rules.

Comment: From what I remember it is mainly an incremental path to a long suspension, perhaps taking three previous suspensions to get to one longer than a year.  Naturally the staff provide little information about specific cases, to guard the privacy of individual users, but occasionally the users themselves provide some details.

Comment: There are some bans network wide for 100 years like [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/759001/user759001). It would be interesting to know why in this case.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Cool  Areally weird example.  If it were a forum for giant tortoises, then maybe 100 years suspension period would make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit of a one year suspension that you referenced is for that by diamond moderators on any one site. However, only Stack Exchange employees may issue network wide suspensions for longer than a year, as the network Meta FAQ [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/562482) post's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125271/562482) states:

> #### What is a network-wide suspension?
>
> A network-wide suspension is applied to all network accounts of a user. It can only be issued by Stack Exchange employees and can be longer than 365 days. The most common reasons for a network-wide suspension are spamming, trolling, and [to cool down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323442/364003).